# tkinter and buildroot on raspberry pi

Tags: linux, tkinter, raspberry-pi, tk-toolkit, buildroot

I've been working on making an image via buildroot for an raspberry pi (specifically, a CM4) and have hit a bit of a roadblock with python and tkinter. The base issue is that I've tried including python as well as some other built-in python3-packages with the build. Some of them are successful but I've been having issues specifically getting tkinter to work appropriately. When I'm in a python shell and try "import tkinter" it throws a traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “<stdin>”, line 1, in <module>
File “/usr/lib/python311/tkinter/__init__.py”, line 38 in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘_tkinter’
```

I understand what the error itself means but I'd like to figure out why this isn't getting included in the build. I understand that 'tkinter' itself is a wrapper for accessing the tk/tcl module and isn't just a standalone module by itself. I also understand the issue between python2 vs python3 and the "Tk" vs "tk" and have verified that's not the issue, I'm currently using Python3.11.

In searching around on the internet, I've come across a couple solutions and done some troubleshooting to try and resolve the issue but none of them have given me a positive result, so here's everything I've tried:

-I found that by default python (via buildroot) did not have tk enabled. I updated the `/packages/python3/python.mk` file and changed all the `--disable tk` statements to `--enable tk`. Built a new image and flashed, still unable to "import tkinter".

-I additionally included the tcl and tk target packages (under "Language interpreter" and "graphical interface", respectively). Built a new image and flashed, still unable to "import tkinter".

-I additionally included python-pip with the intent of installing tcl and tk with pip. Before installing, I ran "pip list" and verified that the other pre-configured python modules i had chosen for the build are shown.

-Using `pip install tk` and `pip install tcl` i was able to install both tk and tcl through pip. After doing so "pip list" would should the package as installed with an appropriate revision. I tried both individually as well as both together. Built a new image and flashed, still unable to "import tkinter".

-With additional searching, i was able to find that some others were experiencing the same/similar issue and there were several patches i tried. I created a global patch folder and configured the global patch directory. The directory is one level up (outside) of my buildroot dir. I additionally included the patches in a "/python3/" directory within the global patch dir. Built a new image and flashed, still unable to "import tkinter".
[Patches 1 and 2](https://buildroot.uclibc.narkive.com/AqB5r8ku/tkinter)
[Additional patch 3](https://github.com/unframework/desk-timer/blob/c9c11ac042cd84a6b504f82805940e16cb934151/nano-buildroot/patches/python3/1000-Always-Enable-Tkinter.patch)

After all the changes I'm kind of at a loss on where/what to look at next. I verified in the flashed image (without any additional changes) that under `/usr/..../python3.11/` there is a tkinter folder that has an `__init__.py` script as expected (which is what I'm assuming is showing in the callback error). As mentioned, all of my other packages I'm able to use in a python terminal like `import can` for `python-can` with the one exception that trying to use `from PIL import ImageTk` gets a similar error saying "unable to locate _tkinter". This is expected since that particular library also depends on tkinter, it was just another verification that other packages are unable to locate it.

The existence of the `/usr/..../python3.11/tkinter` folder leads me to believe that tkinter is being added/built with python but there's something with the configuration that's not correct. However, it's odd that even using `pip` I can't get the reference to work. The last bit of looking around I had done, others (in a full blown linux distro) had similar issues and it was resolved with installing via a package manager. That's what's making me believe I'm missing a configuration or a package somewhere, just for the life of me I can't find what or where.

Comment: See the discussion on the mailing list: https://lore.kernel.org/buildroot/3ac4d88c-4e69-4a64-b2ca-ceff46d3c7dd@mind.be/T/#m8dacaad6ef391b86aba31e184b1aa6f2c65dd058

Comment: @Arnout I was just coming here after updating the mailing list that the solution works. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The full discussion in the mailing list is linked in response to my initial question via @Arnout's response (who pointed out my issue). Just to summarize here to mark as an "answer":

The full solution was to modify the python.mk file `path "/package/python3/python.mk` with:

1. change "disable-tk" to "enable-tk"
2. add the line "PYTHON3_DEPENDENCIES += tk". I did this around line ~70-75 where the other python package dependencies were defined.

Comment: I hope to see a patch on the mailing list that adds tk as an option, which will make this answer irrelevant :-)